# Reading MODBUS on ESP32

Tags: esp32, serial-data, rs485, modbus

I'm working on a project for Smart Meter in this I'm reading MODBUS RS485 on **ESP32** via **MAX485 TTL To RS485**

**Overview** : So, basic flow is, reading MODBUS as per MOSBUS Mapping list given by Smart Meter Manufacturers, I added those hardcoded values in code, read those register values one by one, convert the reading to decimal/float, arrange all required reading in specific format, send the JSON data with https POST request. And then further display those on graph or whatever on server.

*Note : I'm reading only 4 slave ID's as of now. So maximum 4 Numbers of meter can be connected once at a time.*

**Testing Scenario** *(a lab with less noise and interference around*) : I'm able to read data on ESP32 perfectly fine, with changing MODBUS Slave IDs on the meter, even while running.

**Onsite Scenario** *(a place with HIGH voltage Electrical Panel)* : Sometime it reads data perfectly fine, Some it reads only some of the Slave IDs (Out of 4), other time there is no data readings on ESP32

**Debugging** : To rectify the onsite issue, I checked if the meter is working fine or not with *RS485-to-USB* converter and read data on MODSCAN Application on PC. And meter is working perfectly fine. Then what I noticed is, ESP32 also started getting reading while I have connected *RS485-to-USB* converter in parallel.
[image]

**And if I removed the *RS485-to-USB* converter, ESP32 immediately stopped reading any data.**

**Temporary Solution** : To fix this, I removed the *RS485-to-USB* converter from my PC, and given direct 5V supply to *RS485-to-USB* Converter. And ESP32 started reading data again from MODBUS.
[image]

**Question I need help with are**

1. I couldn't understand what does the *RS485-to-USB* converter
   connection in parallel doing.
2. Does it helping in improving RS485 signal and as a repeater?
3. What is the easier way to overcome this, as hardware as well as if only firmware fix is possible?

Some References and term I used above

1. ESP32 30 Pins
2. *RS485-to-USB*

[image]

3. MAX485 TTL To RS485

[image]

- PCB inside Panel :
  [image]

**Additional as Required**

- Meter Manufacturer 1 A-B:50.5 Ohm      B-A:42.9K Ohm
- Meter Manufacturer 2 A-B:0.329M Ohm    B-A:0.327M Ohm
- MAX485 to TTL        A-B:120 Ohm       B-A:120 Ohm
- RS485-to_USB         A-B:26.5 Ohm      B-A:26.3 Ohm

Comment: Could you please re-write the post, because I cannot understand what's going on. How are you connecting the ESP32 to the modules? Where are your grounds? This needs a lot more to determine how to fix this; it indeed seems like a noise issue. I would say that this can probably be fixed with an RS485 repeater. It also potentially sounds like you might be missing a terminating resistor.

Comment: @jsotola My bad, please take a look again. let me know if there is any other I can provide you to understand the issue I'm facing

Comment: @NickS. I rewrite the question in detail now, please take a look again

Comment: 1) How long is your cable, RS485 requires twist pair with shielding, not just two plain wire, this is especially important in the noisy application environment. 2) RS485 requires two terminal resistors (120 ohms) at the two end of the bus, maybe your MAX485 module doesn't have the termination resistor, but your USB-RS454 dongle provided that...

Comment: @JustdoinGodswork can you measure the resistance between A and B on the MAX485 module? When it's powered off. How about on the meters? If you can power them off. Also, the last picture shows me that the ESP32 is simply connected to the RS485-USB dongle thru the MAX485 module, how does that enable you to read meter data?

Comment: @hcheung At one location it's not even 1 meter long, just three meters are connected with different slave IDs (ID:1, ID:2, and ID:3). But there are CTs nearby of 2000/5A ratio. So I'm not sure if that is causing the issue.
I'm using CAT6 for RS485 between Meters but from the last meter to ESP32 its plain wire as shown in last image (connection to orange Screw-Terminal connector)

Comment: @NickS. Added the required resistance values in the above question. In the last picture you can see an orange colored Screw Terminal, that's where I connected RS485 from Electric Meter (yellow colored two wire refer last picture)

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem just about the resistor issue. Because if it's a resistor issue, it should be fixed even with RS485-to-USB connected in parallel without any power. but ESP32 only reads when the USB connected to a power source as I showed in the picture above of Temporary Solution.

Comment: @JustdoinGodswork those don't look good per se, but I don't know how you're measuring them. We have verified that the module has a terminating resistor and that's good. One thing I don't understand - have you tried plugging the meter's RS485 connection into the green connector on the MAX485 module or are you solely using the orange terminals? If yes, why? Are the two connected on the board?

Comment: @NickS. For measuring resistance, I removed all connections from the meter, MAX485 Converter module, and USB. Then use a multimeter in resistance-measuring mode.  The orange connector comes out of the casing/box, so I'm using that for meter RS485 as of now. Also, they are shorted on the PCB with A to A and B to B. This already works perfectly fine while testing in lab with the orange connector only.

Comment: @JustdoinGodswork let's continue in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152155/reading-modbus-on-esp32-q-a).